# Setting MMDevice WaveFormat Programmatically

Tags: c#, windows, naudio

I've attempted to the Wave Format of an audio device using the solution proposed here :
[Setting MMDevice WaveFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57362216/setting-mmdevice-waveformat)

Using the code proposed (after modifying NAudio that is) works fine when I try to set the Wave Format to 48000Hz,16Bits,1ch but fails when I try to set to 32000Hz,16Bits,1ch or any other wave format. I've checked that all the wave formats are proposed by the windows sound manager settings Popup

Any idea why I can only set on wave format ?

EDIT : My client's software uses 5 Jabra headsets plugged into the computer via a usb hub. Because of the usb performance limitations, it is necessary to set the devices à 32Khz in order to save bandwidth, especially if we want to plug more headsets in the future and until we can find a better way to plug so many headsets into the machine. Anyway that does not really explain why it fails to set the headset à 32Khz and succeeds at 48Khz (it fails at 44.1Hz as well btw). As a temporary measure I am using the CLI version of the tool SoundVolumeView and it succeeds in setting all the devices to 32Khz. Just was hoping to do everything with NAudio.

Comment: Why do you want to change it? In Windows audio devices almost always work at 44.1 or 48kHz. If you want to capture or play audio at a different sample rate, then you'd either need to use exclusive mode (and even then not every format will be supported), or just take advantage of the fact that WASAPI supports built-in sample rate conversion.